# what is the probability that at least one does not work?

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose that you just received a shipment of six televisions and two are defective.
If two televisions are randomly selected, compute the probability that both
televisions work.

here is my work and steps to solve it
I believe you should set up a fraction of the working televisions over the total televisions like this (4/6)*(3/5) E=(4/6) and F=(3/5) P(E and F)
6=total televisions
2=don't work
4=work

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: okay thanks for the assist!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

First pick one tv. Then pick another.Probability(both good)
=Pr(first good)Pr(second tv good| given that first was good)
=$\frac{4}{6} \times \frac {3}{5}=\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: thanks I will do that